Flutter onTap Gesture closure not updating
The data coming from the view model is supposed to be listened in the view, and the setState make it rebuild.
The refresh is correct with the child widget (secondChildWidget) but it's not updating with the modal one inside the onTap closure (firstChildWidget).
How to make it update ?
Both are stateless.
This is my code:
class MyView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyView({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyView> createState() => _MyViewState();
}

class _MyViewState extends State<MyView> {

    final ViewModel viewModel = ViewModel();

    String item = "";

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        viewModel.item.listen((value) {
           setState(() { 
              item = value;
           });
        });
     }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
                isScrollControlled: true,
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                    return firstChildWidget(item);
                });
             },
            child: secondChildWidget(item),
          );
     }
}


Try to wrap your firstChildWidget inside StatefulBuilder Widget

You are instantiating a new Viewmodel instance by writing
final ViewModel viewModel = ViewModel();

I'm guessing that this viewmodel's item is never being changed.
I'm assuming that the instance that actual has changes is another one.
It's hard to tell how to solve it because it depends on the rest of your project. You need to look into state management in order to understand how to do this. It might simply work by making the item inside the viewmodel static but in general that's a bad approach, especially if you need multiple instances of this model.

the item is changing, because I'm printing the different values, also the secondChildWidget is updated correctly! so no doubt about it

I think it would help a lot if you showed the code of firstChildWidget and secondChildWidget. There's a good chance the error lies there

showModalBottomSheet is stateless widget by default. If you wrap the child of showModalBottomSheet by stateful builder it may resolve your issue
class MyView extends StatefulWidget {


const MyView({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyView> createState() => _MyViewState();
}

class _MyViewState extends State<MyView> {
  final ViewModel viewModel = ViewModel();

  String item = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    viewModel.item.listen((value) {
      setState(() {
        item = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                return firstChildWidget(item);
              },)
            });
      },
      child: secondChildWidget(item),
    );
  }
}


tried but not working
